# How can I get \hyperlink to display the section number of the \hypertarget?

Tags: hyperlink, hypertarget

I am working with a document class which provides an environment called sheet, together with a \sheetlink command to provide a hyperlink to a specific sheet. A much reduced example demonstrating the key features is shown in the following source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\newcounter{sheetnum}[section]

\newenvironment{sheet}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{sheetnum}
\label{#1}
\hypertarget{#1}{\underline{Sheet \thesection.\thesheetnum}}
}

\newcommand{\sheetlink}[1]{Sheet \hyperlink{1}{\thesection.\ref*{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\section{One}

This is a reference to \sheetlink{sheet:first}

\section{Two}
\label{sec:two}

This is a reference to \sheetlink{sheet:first}

\begin{sheet}{sheet:first}
This is the first sheet in \autoref{sec:two}
\end{sheet}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:
[image]

It works as intended when the \sheetlink command references a sheet in the same section, but of course it gets the section number wrong when \sheetlink is referencing a sheet in a different section, because it uses \thesection, which will be the current section number, not the section containing the sheet.

How do I modify this so that \sheetlink prints the section number of the section containing the sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\newcounter{sheetnum}[section]
\renewcommand\thesheetnum{\thesection.\arabic{sheetnum}}

\newenvironment{sheet}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{sheetnum}%
\label{#1}%
\underline{Sheet \thesheetnum}}

\newcommand{\sheetlink}[1]{Sheet \ref{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{One}

This is a reference to \sheetlink{sheet:first}

\section{Two}
\label{sec:two}

This is a reference to \sheetlink{sheet:first}

\begin{sheet}{sheet:first}
This is the first sheet in \autoref{sec:two}
\end{sheet}

\end{document}
```

[image]